# Android, How to play WAV file programmatically

Tags: android, mp3, wav, playback

I have may file.wav in my directory. Then in parallel, I have to play is with an mp3 file.

See the code below:

```
String recordedFile = "/storage/sdcard0/app/file.wav";
MediaPlayer recordedSong = new MediaPlayer();

try {
  recordedSong = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, 
  Uri.fromFile(recordedFile));
  recordedSong.prepare();
  recordedSong.start();
}
  catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Error: Creation failed and it throws IOException

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to create raw folder and put your file there, use this

```
public void number(int num, Context ctx) {
                 AssetManager am;
        try {
            am = ctx.getAssets();
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = am.openFd("android.resource://"+getPackageName+"/"+R.raw.your_file_name);
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(),
                    afd.getLength());
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
            player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.release();
                }

            });
            player.setLooping(false);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using int num as parameter if you never use that parameter?

Comment: @Windgate Maybe he removed the unimportant logic for this question but didn't change method signature to be able to test it without breaking the whole project:)

Answer (score 8):

I've tried @aangwi answer but got FileNodeFoundException

```
final AssetFileDescriptor afd = myactivity.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.your_file);
final FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = afd.getFileDescriptor();
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
try {
    player.setDataSource(fileDescriptor, afd.getStartOffset(),
    afd.getLength());
    player.setLooping(false);
    player.prepare();
    player.start();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    LOGGER.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it for me!

Answer (score 4):

This works for me (Kotlin):

```
val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(
                    context,
                    R.raw.sound)
mediaPlayer.start()
```

Comment: I don't have a /raw foldear created in /Resources, but even if I create it and store a file there with the name sound.wav this doesn't create the R.raw.sound ID for me so my app can't play it