# How to combine 2 file audio wav from raw to one new wav?

Tags: android, audio

i'm new in android programming , i want to combine 2 file audio wav  to one new wav, and i get answer with this code

```
     import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.SequenceInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;

public class WavAppender {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String wavFile1 = "D:\\wav1.wav";
        String wavFile2 = "D:\\wav2.wav";

        try {
            AudioInputStream clip1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wavFile1));
            AudioInputStream clip2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wavFile2));

            AudioInputStream appendedFiles = 
                            new AudioInputStream(
                                new SequenceInputStream(clip1, clip2),     
                                clip1.getFormat(), 
                                clip1.getFrameLength() + clip2.getFrameLength());

            AudioSystem.write(appendedFiles, 
                            AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, 
                            new File("D:\\wavAppended.wav"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but, code above is for java, how if convert in android ? how to combine 2 file audio wav from raw to one new wav ?

thanks , sorry with my english  .

Comment: instead u can setOncomplete Lister on first wav file and then play second immediately..

Comment: any tutorial ? please

Comment: i can provide you code snip, dont hv tuts, these wav files are only audio right?

Comment: can u plz show code where u r playing ur wav file

Comment: i not yet write code, but this >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606873/android-how-to-play-wav-file-programmatically

Comment: ok below answer will work fine try it and let me know

Answer (score 0):

```
private MediaPlayer mp;
mp = MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity.this,R.raw.monika);


 mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

 // play second wav file
 }
 });
 mp.start();
```

> set a flag so that onComplete lister of second media player should not
>   be played