# MediaPlayer doesn't work, error (1, -2147483648), Prepare failed.: status=0x1

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer, wav

I am just trying to play a simple three-second WAV file and everything I try seems to give me some weird error. I have been going at this for about half an hour and all of the other solutions online give me more errors.

The .wav is in the `/res/raw/` directory and is 1.17MB, 2822kbps and about three seconds in length.

Code:

```
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        FileDescriptor fd=getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.flipwav).getFileDescriptor();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp.setDataSource(fd);
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
                player.start();
            }
        });
        mp.prepare();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get this error:

```
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
I/System.out: java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

I have tried changing `mp.prepare()` to `mp.prepareAsync()` but this happens:

```
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
```

Is it a problem with my code or the file itself? I have tried multiple files including an mp3 and the result is always the same. I am using a Windows 10 computer with Android Studio.

Comment: Have you added the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the manifest?

Comment: And maybe call mp.prepare() before setOnPreparedListener

Comment: @Slartibartfast I have done both of those, yet I still get the same error. Thanks for your response, though. :)

Comment: Just this piece of code work for you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17609071/1081340 ?

Comment: @Slartibartfast Sorry for the delayed response. Thanks for your comment,  it solved my problem. :)